# Print number of recursions in C

Tags: c, recursion, binary

So I have an exercise that goes like this:
Code a program that user inputs 2 natural numbers X and Y. The output must print the number of combinations that are recursively computed to generate binary numbers using X 1s and Y 0s.
For example, user inputs 2 and 3. The combinations of 2 and 3 generating binary numbers are:

1. 00011
2. 00101
3. 00110
4. 01001
5. 01010
6. 01100
7. 10001
8. 10010
9. 10100

**10**. 11000

The program must print "**10**".

So I've coded the recursion but I cant figure out a way to print the number "10".
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int recursion(int a, int z)
{

    if(a==0 && z==0)
    {
        printf(".");
        return 1;
    }

    if(a!=0 && z==0)
        return recursion(a-1,z);
    if(a==0 && z!=0)
        return recursion(a,z-1);
    if(a!=0 && z!=0)
        return recursion(a-1,z)+recursion(a,z-1);

}

int main()
{

    int a,z;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &z);

    recursion(a,z);

    return 0;
}
```

This code only prints 10 "." instead of the number of dots that I need. Any thoughts?

Comment: You mean you don't know how to print the value returned by `recursion()`?

Comment: https://ideone.com/f8rHpc

Comment: Unrelated to your question, writing recursive messes such as this is terribly poor practice and this exercise is focusing on learning harmful practices instead of good ones.

Comment: Is it a recursion assignment? Because this task may be solved using [combination](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/other/combination/). And the answer is C(x + y, x)

Comment: Never use scanf() on user input without checking the return value. Your `a` and `z` may be uninitialized. (If I had a penny for every time I wrote that... don't they *teach* kids these things anymore?)

Answer (score 0):

Your program already returns its level of recursion, a simple way to print it could be:

```
int main()
{
    int a, z, level, read;

    do {
        read = scanf("%d %d", &a, &z);
        if (read != 2) {
            printf("Incorrect input, please try again"); 
        }
    } while (read != 2);

    level = recursion(a,z);
    printf("\n%d\n", level); /* Newline characters added to improve readability */
    
    return 0;
}
```

So the output would be the dots you are printing on line 9 and the level of recursion (10 in your example).

```
..........
10
```

Comment: Please add return code check to that `scanf()`. if the user enters something other than two integers, you're working on uninitialized variables (=> UB).

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int recursion(int a, int z)
{ int d;

    if(a==0 && z==0)
    {
        d++;
       
        return 1;
    }

    if(a!=0 && z==0)
        return recursion(a-1,z);
    if(a==0 && z!=0)
        return recursion(a,z-1);
    if(a!=0 && z!=0)
        return recursion(a-1,z)+recursion(a,z-1);

}

int main()
{

    int a,z,d;

    scanf("%d %d", &a, &z);

    d=recursion(a,z);
printf("%d",d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `d` in `recursion()` is not initialized so the value is meaningless.  It also isn't accessible outside the function.

Comment: Please add return code check to that `scanf()`. if the user enters something other than two integers, you're working on uninitialized variables (=> UB).